# codeigniter is not working after uploading in the server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My site `http://www.bishal.prtia.com/prT_base/` throw an `404` error while loading in the server.

It works perfectly in the `localhost`. I tried changing everything that mentioned in this forum like changing `.htaccess` to web.config and changing base url routing config etc but it still throws an error.

Comment: Basically you need to show us your code and the other config to determine the problem

Comment: should i copy paste the whole code here?? Please specify anything u want to see

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things once again:

1. Make sure your base_url is proper as per your website address, not localhost
2. Check routes.php file for default controller and make sure it is correct.
3. Make sure .htaccess looks like

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|upload|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]`

Then check following thigs:
Config.php

1. $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.bishal.prtia.com/prT_base/';
2. $config['index_page'] = '';
3. $config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';

Routes.php

1. $route['default_controller'] = 'your controller name (like welcome)';
2. $route['404_override'] = '';
3. $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Make sure php file name of controller start with capital letter like Welcome and also inside that file as well when inherit from CI_Controller

Function inside Welcome.php:

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('your view file');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried like you said but now my main page isnt loading. What did i do wrong??

Comment: @BishalChhetri Does your prT_base is the controller name or the folder which contains all your code?

Comment: prT_base in the main folder name which contains everything

Comment: Then check following thigs:
1. $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.bishal.prtia.com/prT_base/';

Comment: Edited my answer please check again. It should work other wise check error log

Comment: Its still not working is there a way i can show u my code ??    use login id :Bishal@gg.cc and password:hack

Comment: Send me config.php, routes.php and your defaultcontroller.php files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few steps.

- Update `base_url` in `config.php`
- Update `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess`
- Set Permissions
- if still not workable, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in `index.php` and see what it says

Comment: Can u please elaborate ??  my config.php have   $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.bishal.prtia.com/prT_base';     Rewritebase is RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]   . Please elaborate 3rd and 4rth

Comment: Well, after uploading, you need to change base_url like locally it will be something `localhost/codeigniter` and for online it will be `http://www.bishal.prtia.com/prT_base/`. Then if its in sub directory of main hosting then you need to set `rewritebase` in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error. I changed my .htaccess file [WORKED FOR ME] :-

.htaccess for Live Server :-

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess for Localhost :-

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```